# Cinnamon CSD and Firefox = unnecessary border around Firefox window

Tags: firefox, archlinux, cinnamon

Cinnamon + Client Side Decorator + Firefox dev edition (60 beta) = unnecessary border around Firefox window - also after maximize window.
How change this?

The wine is Cinnamona? Firefox? Theme (I have a standard)?

Comment: same problem here https://imgur.com/a/EkHMv

Comment: Here i created a fork of OSX-Arc-Darker and used [this](https://github.com/lucascimino6/OSXMint) theme's metacity to fix the issue [github link](https://github.com/surajmandalcell/OSX-Arc-Darker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=265963&p=1446023) from forums.linuxmint.com:

> Switching to Mint-Y window theme [...] removes the dark gray border.